# Вопросы про enum в C и C++

Tags: c++, c, enum

Я пытаюсь понять различия в семантике `enum` между `C` и `C++`.

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие их следующих моих предположений верны, а какие нет, и почему:

1) В языке `C` тип `enum` гарантированно имеет фиксированный нижележащий тип (зависит от реализации). Следовательно, мы получаем соответствующие гарантии. Например, гарантии по размеру. К примеру, при экспорте из `DLL` функции, аргумент которой имеет тип `enum`, мы можем гарантировать, что вызывающая сторона может работать с таким аргументом как с обычным `int` (зависит от реализации).

2) В языке `C++` переменная типа `enum` не имеет фиксированного нижележащего типа, если он не указан явно. Если верить `Стандарту`, то при отсутствии явного задания нижележащего типа для `enum` компилятор имеет полное право использовать такое количество битов, которое необходимо и достаточно для хранения только определенных (имеющихся, существующих) перечислителей перечисления.

3) `C++` запрещает преобразование (при помощи `static_cast`) в `enum` (без указанного нижележащего типа), если исходная величина не может быть представлена в диапазоне возможных значений указанного перечисления.

4) `C` позволяет преобразование между любыми перечислениями, потому что все перечисления имеют одинаковый нижележащий тип.

Comment: 3) это Ада запрещает, а С++ спокойно даст отстрелить ногу

Comment: Под  `запрещает` я имел в виду то, что `Стандарт` трактует такое действие, как ошибочное, с неизвестными последствиями.

Comment: 1) в gcc есть опция *-fshort-enums* если ее использовали то возможно не совместимость , а в некоторых компиляторах можно указывать размер _enum_